# Filter in get_context_data and get_query_set not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a listview where I'm trying to filter out products by category. Some products have a subcategory. When a product has a subcategory I want the listview to display them by subcategory.
Problem is: The listview works perfect for items with a subcategory, but does not work for items who do not have a subcategory. Where am I taking a wrong turn here?

Models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    category_picture = ResizedImageField(upload_to='category/', null=True, blank=True)
    category_info = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    category_video = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.sub_category is None:
            return self.category_name
        else:
            return f" {self.sub_category}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['category_name']

class Bottle(models.Model):
    category_name = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bottle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bottle_info = models.TextField()
    bottle_tasting_notes = models.TextField()
    bottle_barcode = models.IntegerField()
    bottle_image = ResizedImageField(upload_to='bottles/',null=True, blank=True)
    bottle_shop_link = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.brand}, {self.bottle_name}"
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['bottle_name']
```

View:

```
class BottlesByCategoryView(ListView):
    model = Bottle
    context_object_name = 'bottles'

    #Filter bij subcategory in the category model. If no subcategory exists, load by category_name
    def get_queryset(self):
        if Bottle.objects.filter(category_name__sub_category=self.kwargs['category']) is None:
            return Bottle.objects.filter(category_name__category_name=self.kwargs['category'])   
        else:
            return Bottle.objects.filter(category_name__sub_category=self.kwargs['category'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BottlesByCategoryView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if Bottle.objects.filter(category_name__sub_category=self.kwargs['category']) is None:
            context['category_info'] = Category.objects.filter(category_name=self.kwargs['category'])
        else:
            context['category_info'] = Category.objects.filter(sub_category=self.kwargs['category'])
        return context
```

URLS:

```
path('BottlesByCategory/<str:category>/',BottlesByCategoryView.as_view(template_name='academy/bottlesByCat_list.html'),name='bottlesByCat_list'),
```

Can i not use if statements in the get_context_data and get_query_set?

Comment: I assume you want a single queryset with all objects filtered either by category or sub-category ... that is not what your code does. The "if" statement decides either the filter by category or by subcategory for all elements depending on if it finds a single element with a fitting subcategory. First to clarify what is the exact behaviour you want. Then decide to filter with an OR logic.

Comment: Can you add a print statement between 
 ```if Bottle.objects.filter(category_name__sub_category=self.kwargs['category']) is None: ```
    and 
 ```return Bottle.objects.filter(category_name__category_name=self.kwargs['category']) ```
and check the result of the queryset ?